# Issue while including category name in url "{cate-name}/{se-name}" in category landing page in Nop Commerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce 3.40 and i want to include Parent category name in url of category landing page which i can able to do by
adding parent category name manually in sename from admin side while creating category for example i have Parent category saree then in sename i am giving like "saree/test" 
and adding below code in 
Nop.web\Infrastructure\GenericUrlRouteProvider.cs

```
 routes.MapGenericPathRoute("AllUrls1",
              "{*generic_se_name}",
              new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl" },
              new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

this way i am able to get my result.But its making problem in checkout page(i am using one page checkout).Problem is after billing address selection instead of going to shipping address section its redirecting to cart page.

Is there anything i need to do extra that i am missing  for this issue or any other way to get url i want for category landing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this like this way best way to do this is to modify code in the nopCommerce route handler. Go to below file and modify it.

```
/Presentation/Nop.Web.Framework/Seo/GenericPathRoute.cs
```